# Some softwares are not working after uninstall bodhi desktop from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I am trying to open synaptic from termial. `gksudo synaptic` but I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gksudo", line 5, in <module>
    import esudo.esudo as esudo
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/esudo/esudo.py", line 13, in <module>
    from efl import ecore
ImportError: libecore.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed `sudo apt-get install --force-yes moksha packagekit bodhi-desktop-e17` and uninstall it later with `sudo apt-get remove --force-yes moksha packagekit bodhi-desktop-e17`
and then I used `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get remove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean the pc. But some software are not working afterwards. Please can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libecore1`

Answer (score 0):

First install `packagekit` again

```
sudo apt-get install packagekit
```

---

Now install or reinstall the package `libecore1` via

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libecore1
```

Why? That's why:

```
% apt-file search libecore.so.1
libecore1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libecore.so.1
libecore1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libecore.so.1.8.6
```

Comment: If that fails, reinstall ubuntu-desktop perhpas

Comment: I followed the answer and then also tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop but I still have the problem... :(